# Test Results Repository Solutions?

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I have been searching for a while now and am surprised that I can't find any solutions out there for test result storage with grouping and searching capabilities.

I'd like a service or self hosted solution that supports:

- storing test results in xunit/junit organized by keyword.  In other words, I want to keep all my "test process A" test results together and all my "test process B" results together.  I want to store failure traces and overall pass/fail at a minimum
- get last run results for keyword: get the last "auth" test results with failure details
- get run history results by keyword in some format
- search of some sort on test results

I happen to be have:

- Cypress tests
- typescript/mocha tests without cypress
- custom test framework tests that will need custom reporters

but I am fine with any test results solution that supports a generic input like xunit.

I am definitely open to suggestions that use any other storage system that can accomplish this even if it isn't strictly a test results tool.

Comment: Has `reportportal.io` satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Thanks!  Looking at reportportal.